Pandas concat on resampled data frames results in empty data frame
I have the below code:
    raster = "1s"
    
    # Resample data to a shared time raster (e.g. 1s) and combine into a single data frame
    dfs_resampled = [df.resample(raster).ffill() for df in dfs]
    print("dfs_resampled",dfs_resampled)

    # Join resampled data frames into a single data frame
    df_custom = pd.concat(dfs_resampled, axis=1, join="inner")
    print("df_custom",df_custom)

It produces the below result:
dfs_resampled [                     CAN1_VD_S00_TotalVehicleDistance  CAN1_VD_S00_TripDistance
t                                                                              
2020-01-13 14:01:27                               NaN                       NaN
2020-01-13 14:01:28                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:01:29                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:01:30                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:01:31                          464632.5                  464632.5
...                                               ...                       ...
2020-01-13 14:04:39                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:40                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:41                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:42                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:43                          464632.5                  464632.5

[197 rows x 2 columns],                      CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnCrnksBrthrOlSprtrSpd  ...  CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnIntkMnfldCmmnddPrssr
t                                                            ...                                        
2020-01-13 14:01:28                                     NaN  ...                                     NaN
2020-01-13 14:01:29                                  6333.0  ...                                  82.625
2020-01-13 14:01:30                                  6329.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:31                                  6333.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:32                                  6329.0  ...                                  82.750
...                                                     ...  ...                                     ...
2020-01-13 14:04:39                                  6251.0  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:40                                  6255.0  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:41                                  6254.0  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:42                                  6250.0  ...                                 107.000
2020-01-13 14:04:43                                  6250.0  ...                                 107.000

[196 rows x 4 columns]]
df_custom Empty DataFrame
Columns: [CAN1_VD_S00_TotalVehicleDistance, CAN1_VD_S00_TripDistance, CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnCrnksBrthrOlSprtrSpd, CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnExhstGsRrltn1Vlv2Pstn, CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnExhstGsRrltn1VlvPstn, CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnIntkMnfldCmmnddPrssr]
Index: []

My expected result was to get a single data frame, df_custom, that would contain the inner join of the two separate resampled data frames on the same time raster. Yet, instead I am getting an empty data frame - as if there are no matches between the two separate resampled data frames.
I have tried various methods to determine if the resampled timestamps align and from what I can tell they should. Am I using the pd.concat function incorrectly?
Note: If I change my raster to 5s instead of 1s, then I get the expected result as below:
dfs_resampled [                     CAN1_VD_S00_TotalVehicleDistance  CAN1_VD_S00_TripDistance
t                                                                              
2020-01-13 14:01:25                               NaN                       NaN
2020-01-13 14:01:30                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:01:35                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:01:40                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:01:45                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:01:50                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:01:55                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:00                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:05                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:10                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:15                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:20                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:25                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:30                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:35                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:40                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:45                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:50                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:02:55                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:00                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:05                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:10                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:15                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:20                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:25                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:30                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:35                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:40                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:45                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:50                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:03:55                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:00                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:05                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:10                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:15                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:20                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:25                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:30                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:35                          464632.5                  464632.5
2020-01-13 14:04:40                          464632.5                  464632.5,                      CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnCrnksBrthrOlSprtrSpd  ...  CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnIntkMnfldCmmnddPrssr
t                                                            ...                                        
2020-01-13 14:01:25                                     NaN  ...                                     NaN
2020-01-13 14:01:30                                  6329.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:35                                  6335.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:40                                  6335.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:45                                  6335.0  ...                                  82.625
2020-01-13 14:01:50                                  6333.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:55                                  6331.0  ...                                  82.625
2020-01-13 14:02:00                                  6332.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:05                                  6331.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:10                                  6323.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:15                                  6321.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:20                                  6315.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:25                                  6310.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:30                                  6306.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:35                                  6302.0  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:40                                  6313.0  ...                                  82.500
2020-01-13 14:02:45                                  6307.0  ...                                  82.500
2020-01-13 14:02:50                                  6304.0  ...                                  82.625
2020-01-13 14:02:55                                  6301.0  ...                                  59.250
2020-01-13 14:03:00                                  6305.0  ...                                  55.375
2020-01-13 14:03:05                                  6301.0  ...                                  55.000
2020-01-13 14:03:10                                  6306.0  ...                                  55.375
2020-01-13 14:03:15                                  6303.0  ...                                  55.000
2020-01-13 14:03:20                                  6300.0  ...                                  55.250
2020-01-13 14:03:25                                  6294.0  ...                                  55.125
2020-01-13 14:03:30                                  6296.0  ...                                  55.250
2020-01-13 14:03:35                                  6290.0  ...                                  55.000
2020-01-13 14:03:40                                  6288.0  ...                                  55.250
2020-01-13 14:03:45                                  6281.0  ...                                  55.375
2020-01-13 14:03:50                                  6282.0  ...                                  55.375
2020-01-13 14:03:55                                  6274.0  ...                                 105.625
2020-01-13 14:04:00                                  6270.0  ...                                 106.125
2020-01-13 14:04:05                                  6268.0  ...                                 106.500
2020-01-13 14:04:10                                  6269.0  ...                                 106.750
2020-01-13 14:04:15                                  6267.0  ...                                 106.750
2020-01-13 14:04:20                                  6265.0  ...                                 106.750
2020-01-13 14:04:25                                  6256.0  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:30                                  6257.0  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:35                                  6255.0  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:40                                  6255.0  ...                                 106.875

[40 rows x 4 columns]]
df_custom                      CAN1_VD_S00_TotalVehicleDistance  ...  CAN1_EEC7_S01_EngnIntkMnfldCmmnddPrssr
t                                                      ...                                        
2020-01-13 14:01:25                               NaN  ...                                     NaN
2020-01-13 14:01:30                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:35                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:40                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:45                          464632.5  ...                                  82.625
2020-01-13 14:01:50                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:01:55                          464632.5  ...                                  82.625
2020-01-13 14:02:00                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:05                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:10                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:15                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:20                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:25                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:30                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:35                          464632.5  ...                                  82.750
2020-01-13 14:02:40                          464632.5  ...                                  82.500
2020-01-13 14:02:45                          464632.5  ...                                  82.500
2020-01-13 14:02:50                          464632.5  ...                                  82.625
2020-01-13 14:02:55                          464632.5  ...                                  59.250
2020-01-13 14:03:00                          464632.5  ...                                  55.375
2020-01-13 14:03:05                          464632.5  ...                                  55.000
2020-01-13 14:03:10                          464632.5  ...                                  55.375
2020-01-13 14:03:15                          464632.5  ...                                  55.000
2020-01-13 14:03:20                          464632.5  ...                                  55.250
2020-01-13 14:03:25                          464632.5  ...                                  55.125
2020-01-13 14:03:30                          464632.5  ...                                  55.250
2020-01-13 14:03:35                          464632.5  ...                                  55.000
2020-01-13 14:03:40                          464632.5  ...                                  55.250
2020-01-13 14:03:45                          464632.5  ...                                  55.375
2020-01-13 14:03:50                          464632.5  ...                                  55.375
2020-01-13 14:03:55                          464632.5  ...                                 105.625
2020-01-13 14:04:00                          464632.5  ...                                 106.125
2020-01-13 14:04:05                          464632.5  ...                                 106.500
2020-01-13 14:04:10                          464632.5  ...                                 106.750
2020-01-13 14:04:15                          464632.5  ...                                 106.750
2020-01-13 14:04:20                          464632.5  ...                                 106.750
2020-01-13 14:04:25                          464632.5  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:30                          464632.5  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:35                          464632.5  ...                                 106.875
2020-01-13 14:04:40                          464632.5  ...                                 106.875

[40 rows x 6 columns]



This was solved by rounding to the raster as below:
    raster = "1s"
    
    # Resample and round data to a shared time raster, then combine into a single data frame
    dfs_resampled = [df.resample(raster).ffill() for df in dfs]
    for df in dfs_resampled:
        df.index = df.index.round(raster)

    df_custom = pd.concat(dfs_resampled, axis=1, join="inner")

